# PDF Attachment not receive in mail while sending mail via IPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, calayer

In my application i have to generate PDF and send that attachment using mfmail compose controller.To Generate pdf,i have used CALayer class to rendered uiview as PDF. the generated pdf need to be send as attachment to corresponding user. Now the problem is, at receiver end attachment is visible and received only mail send from iphone not from ipad. while sending the mail it shows perfectly, but not display in mail(In case of sending mail from Ipad). Guide me to resolve this issue. Here is my code for generating PDF.

```
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    
    [pdfView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
    
    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    
    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",[receivedSelectedDict valueForKey:@"reportID"]]];
    NSLog(@"while creating %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
```

**Code for Attaching the PDF as a Composer attachment:**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",[receivedSelectedDict valueForKey:@"reportID"]]];
            NSLog(@"while fetching %@",file);
            NSMutableData *data=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];
            [mailViewController addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:[receivedSelectedDict valueForKey:@"reportID"]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uiview(pdfView) which you rendering as PDF height need to be more when compared to ipad view.
If it less than ipad view it will attach as inline attachment.The inline attachment does not visible by mozila,So better you can view the inline attachment in safari. Instead of inline attachment,If you wants to view as individual attachment, you must increase the height of pdf view.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `mimeType:@"application/pdf"` to `mimeType:@"text/pdf"`, it worked for me when I faced the same problem.